# Getting a contiguous fragment (rectangle) of an image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, numpy-ndarray

I'm building a dataset of surfaces images based on the [opensurfaces dataset](http://opensurfaces.cs.cornell.edu/shapes/substance/all/) but there are several images which have weird and small shapes that are not useful for my use case.

So I'm trying to use OpenCV/Numpy to get from this:

[image: Complete image]

To this:

[image: Desired crop]

So what I need to do is to extract the largest contiguous fragment of pixels (different to the white ones) forming an square or rectangle.

I can get all the white pixels with something like this:

```
image_mastered = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
image_copy = image_mastered.copy()
non_surface = np.all(image_copy == [255,255,255], axis=-1)
image_copy[non_surface] = [255,255,255]
```

But I don't know how to get the desired fragment.

Comment: _"largest contiguous fragment of pixels"_ - by what metric? Is a `10x10` rectangle "larger" or the same "largeness" as a `2x50` rectangle?

Comment: A very similar question, but in matlab: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133895

Comment: Linked question takes in your `non_surface` array and outputs the coordinates in the image of the rectangle

Comment: @Eric thanks for the reference to a similar question, I'll give it a try.